# Onscreen plugin loading in classnames at wrong time

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, addclass

This [onscreen](http://benpickles.github.com/onScreen/) plugin is meant to add classnames only to elements when they are within the viewport, however it seems to be adding the classnames as soon as the page is loaded which isn't what's meant to happen.

```
$(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
  $("#star").filter(":onScreen").addClass('animated bounceInRight');
  }, 0)                             
})
```

I'm using it within this plugin which, is a book effect plugin and I think it conflicts with onscreen in some way: http://pastebin.com/UmyJ6zBW This plugin requires different sections on one page for it to work. Onscreen works when used within the first section but breaks when in others that aren't actually on view. How do I fix this?

Comment: There's a lot of code in that pastebin. Have you considered isolating the issue to a smaller section of code, and creating a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: I can try but I wouldn't know if I would be isolating the correct piece of code or not.

Comment: setInterval(..., 0) !!! Are you sure?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Why whats the problem with doing this? Can I ask what this line of code does?

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Surely if it isn't set to zero, then the animation wouldn't kick in as soon as the elements is in view?

Comment: `setInterval(fn, t)` establishes that function `fn` be called repeatedly every `t` milliseconds. With `t==0`, `fn` will be called as fast as the client processor can manage, consuming processing power and largely denying it from just about everything else - all web pages, all other applications, all processes and all services.

Comment: @Beetroot-Beetroot Okay, so not a good idea but now that I changed it back to 1 second. My content is on display, disappears then plays the animation to bring it back into view. How do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do one of three things.

1. Don't bother. In general you don't need to worry about the style of elements that are not in view.
2. Use `setInterval()` but reduce the interval to the minimum acceptable value but no less than about 20 ms.
3. [preferred] Establish an event handler that fires in response to whatever causes your `#star` element to be moved on/off screen.

For the third approach :

- jQuery animations provide for a `step` callback which fires as each animation step is executed.
- As scrolling the document will also cause elements to come in/out of view, you probably also want to a `scroll` handler.

With care, you should be able to write a single function and use it for both purposes.